# How to set no-ack on virtual hosts in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-federation

My server which uses the federation plugin has 4 virtual channels, each set to 10 prefetch. When 10 messages are not acknowledged the server is stuck.

How can I set no-ack to the virtual host?

Comment: ` the server is stuck` what do you mean? can you please explain?

Comment: @Gabriele please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123190/rabbitmq-keeps-stacking-unacked-messages-although-they-are-rejected-or-acknowled