# RabbitMQ keeps stacking unacked messages although they are rejected or acknowledged

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, bunny, sneakers

My Ruby code below processes RabbitMQ events. I'm using Bunny for Ruby and the [sneakers gem](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers). Although I think I'm acting on all possible events, the local channels are getting stacked with unacked messages. This happens every time the log says something like:

```
sneakers_1          | I, [2017-02-08T19:03:31.088857 #14]  INFO -- : Rejecting 172.21.0.21. Name invalid tld
```

This is my Ruby code:

```
require 'sneakers'

class EventProcessor
  include Sneakers::Worker
  from_queue :edge_requests


  def work(msg)
    msg = JSON.parse(msg)
    domain = msg[':path'].split('/').first
    domain = domain.downcase.sub(/^www\./, '')
    domain = Domain.find_or_initialize_by(name: domain) {|domain| domain.status = :active}
    unless domain.valid?
      Rails.logger.info "Rejecting #{domain.name}. #{domain.errors.full_messages.join(',')}"
      reject!
      return
    end
    domain.persisted? ? domain.touch : domain.save!
    ack!
  rescue
    Rails.logger.error $!
    reject!
  end
end
```

Something is wrong with my `reject!` probably? kind of stuck for hours. I tried to change all the `reject!` with `ack!` but nothing seems to help.

Maybe I'm using `rescue` the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly late answer but faced this issue and the solution is alway return either `ack!` or `reject!`.

So change this:

```
reject!
return
```

to

```
return reject!
```